# Dynamic sheet names based on dependent cells

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if this is simple, but I am new to VBA. I am attempting to set up the my Excel sheet so that when certain cells in the first sheet are changed (eg A1, A2, A3, A4) the names of four other sheets will change to match them. I have found the following formula which works if I change the specific cell on that sheet;

`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        Set Target = Range("A1")
        If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
        On Error GoTo Badname
        ActiveSheet.Name = Left(Target, 31)
        Exit Sub
    Badname:
        MsgBox "Please revise the entry in A1." & Chr(13) _
        & "It appears to contain one or more " & Chr(13) _
        & "illegal characters." & Chr(13)
        Range("A1").Activate
    End Sub
```

`    Unfortunately it will not work if I change A1 to be dependent on one of the four cells on the main sheet specified previously, as it only looks for changes in the sheet it is saved in.

Is there a way to use VBA to look at a cell in one sheet and then change the sheet name of another sheet to match?

Thanks

Comment: It is not as simple as that. You have to check for lot of things like.. If the new name is a valid name.. If you don't have a sheet already with that name etc.. Let me see if I can come up with a sample

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comments, it's not that simple to rename the sheet. You have to check for so many things.

**My Assumptions**

1. You have 5 Sheets in a workbook; `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4` and `Sheet5`
2. When you change cells in `Sheet5`, depending on the cell which changes, `Sheets1-4's` names are changed
3. I am assuming that when `A1` changes, `Sheet1` is renamed. When `A2` changes, `Sheet2` is renamed and so on...

**Logic**

1. Use `Worksheet_Change` event to trap changes to cell `A1`, `A2`, `A3` or `A4`
2. Use Sheet CodeName to change the name
3. Check if the sheet name is valid. A sheet name cannot contain any of these Characters `\ / * ? [ ]`
4. Check if you already have a sheet with the name you want to use for renaming
5. If everything is hunky dory then go ahead and replace

**Code**

See this example. This code goes in the `Sheet5` code area.

```
Dim sMsg As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsName As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    sMsg = "Success"

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            wsName = Left(Target, 31)

            RenameSheet [Sheet1], wsName
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
            wsName = Left(Target, 31)

            RenameSheet [Sheet2], wsName
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3")) Is Nothing Then
            wsName = Left(Target, 31)

            RenameSheet [Sheet3], wsName
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then
            wsName = Left(Target, 31)

            RenameSheet [Sheet4], wsName
        End If
    End If

    MsgBox sMsg
Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub

'~~> Procedure actually renames the sheet
Sub RenameSheet(ws As Worksheet, sName As String)
    If IsNameValid(sName) Then
        If sheetExists(sName) = False Then
            ws.Name = sName
        Else
            sMsg = "Sheet Name already exists. Please check the data"
        End If
    Else
        sMsg = "Invalid sheet name"
    End If
End Sub

'~~> Check if sheet name is valid
Function IsNameValid(sWsn As String) As Boolean
    IsNameValid = True

    '~~> A sheet name cannot contain any of these Characters \ / * ? [ ]
    For i = 1 To Len(sWsn)
        Select Case Mid(sWsn, i, 1)
        Case "\", "/", "*", "?", "[", "]"
            IsNameValid = False
            Exit For
        End Select
    Next
End Function

'~~> Check if the sheet exists
Function sheetExists(sWsn As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sWsn)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then sheetExists = True
End Function
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: @mehow: Thanks for taking the time to appreciate it :)

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks so much for your help. I feel slightly better that it was complicated enough that I would never have worked it out myself, but also slightly worse that I know so little that I didn't even realise how complicated it was.

Comment: Hopefully I might be able to learn a bit from taking apart your code.Thanks again.